# Socket.io and file transfer in Node.js

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am new to nodejs and i am trying to achieve file transfer from a server to a web-client. Say, a server's work is to take a screenshot and send it to the web-client I have achieved connection between the server and client through express and I am able to check to whether the client is connected, since I am using express and socket.io I was hoping to send the captured image through 'socket.broadcast.emit'

This is the code I am using:

```
sources.forEach(function (source) {
   if(source.name === "Entire screen" || source.name === "Screen 1" ){
        if(screenShotPath === ''){
            screenShotPath = path.join(os.tmpdir(),'screenshot.jpeg');
        }
        console.log(screenShotPath);
        io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
            console.log('A new client is conencted');
            socket.broadcast.emit('img', source.thumbnail.toPNG);

        })
        fs.writeFile(screenShotPath,source.thumbnail.toPNG(), function (err) {
            if(err) return console.log(err.message);

            shell.openExternal("file://"+screenShotPath);
            var message = 'Saved SS to ' + screenShotPath;
            screenshotMsg.textContent = message;
        });
   }
});
```

will this work? And can someone please tell me how to receive the sent stream? 
Is this the way to send the image and receive it in the web-client or is there a easier way to achieve this functionality?

Also. is there way to send the image between two servers? Say one server is taking the screenshot and I'll have to save this image in another system which is a server, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

You need to broadcast the base64 encoded image, then use [data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob) to display it.

```
const fs = require('fs');

const imgFile = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
const imgBase64 = new Buffer(imgFile).toString('base64');

socket.broadcast.emit('img', imgBase64);

socket.on('img', (data) => {
  const imgTag = `<img src="data:image/png;base64, ${data}"/>` // inject into DOM
});
```

Comment: SO, should i encode the imaage to base64 and then send it using this code?

Comment: Can you also please tell me which is best way to send this image between two servers? Say one server is the app which takes the screenshot, if i want to save the image to a remote server what should i do? I have edited my question too

Comment: Servers can be "clients" in socket.io too, so you could just have the remote server listen for messages the way clients do, and save the incoming image.

Comment: Can delivery.js be used for this?

Comment: is there a npm for that?

Comment: i m not able to look at the data that is received in the client, it seems to be empty